# Class typedef defined outside of class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a class `C` which has an inner class `T`, and I'd like the details of `T` hidden as an internal implementation of `C`. Methods in `C` are all using pointers to `T`. This is of course possible as:

```
// In header
class C {
public:
  class T;
  T* f();
  void g(T*);
};

// In .cpp
class C::T { /* details here */ };
```

Now my question is, how can I define `C::T` as a type alias of another one, in `.cpp` file. The following doesn't compile at all, but it illustrates what I want to do:

```
// Outside the class C
using C::T = std::string;
```

Is there any workaround to this, while maintaining the goal, i.e. hide the detail of `C::T`?

Comment: Did you mean rather using a template?

Comment: You can't. T isn't an alias, it is a type.

Comment: it sounds like you need to make `C` a class template. `template <typename Type> class C { using T = Type; ... };`

Comment: @NathanOliver, I understand if I define `class T` inside `C`'s declaration, it is not possible. The solution I am looking for doesn't have to keep the line `class T;` inside the `C`'s declaration. It could be `typename T` instead (of course I know this doesn't work either).

Comment: @RSahu, I know this, but it doesn't help hide the implementation of `T`, because whenever I instantiate some `C<T>` I need to give it `T`.

Comment: If you don't know what the `T` is as a user, what can you do with it?

Comment: @Quimby, you don't need to do anything with it. You just retrieve it via `T* C::f()` and use it via `void C::g(T*)`

Comment: @KanLi Ok, that makes sense. But you cannot enforce that by the language, so the user must know what `T` stands for. Becuase how could the compiler compile the user code otherwise? Remember that translation units are compiled separately. My suggestion would be define T as `class T{ std::string data; friend class C;}` Then `g()` method can access the "implementation-defined data".

Comment: Maybe you want to have class T have a private implementation using PIMPL. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: @Quimby. Compiler can definitely compile the user code without knowing what T is as compiler knows for sure how large a pointer is.

Comment: @KanLi Oh, you are right,my bad, sorry.

Comment: You write that you want to hide implementation details, but type `T` is exposed as part of public interface (`T* f(); void g(T*);`). That is user must know what `T` is. Forward declaration at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, it cannot be done. This is my suggestion:

```
// .h
class C {
public:
  struct T;
  T* f();
  void g(T*);
};

// .cpp
struct C::T
{
  IMPL_TYPE data;
  //If one is carefull with lifetimes this can almost in any context act as IMPL_TYPE.
  //And if necessary, the data member can be accessed.
  operator IMPL_TYPE&(){return data};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because the forward declaration `class T;` within class `C` declares a class type whose True Name is `C::T`, and is therefore not identical to the type whose True Name is `std::basic_string<...>`.

You might consider the following:

```
// C.h
#include "internal/T.h"
namespace foo {
class C {
public:
  using T = internal::T;
  // ...
};
}

// internal/T.h
namespace foo { namespace internal {
using T = std::string;
}}
```

Comment: it definitely helps, but still doesn't completely hide the implementation details. Ideally users of class `C` doesn't need to ever see the declaration of `T`.

Comment: @KanLi They don't. If your code is well-documented, then users will not need to read the internal header.

Comment: To the OP: This seems to be your best bet. However, it must be noted that `internal::T` is defined using another level of indirection but it is not really hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come to this would be to have your t derive from string:

```
class C::T : public std::string { ... };
```

Answer (score -1):

`T` can never be truly hidden or redefined to be a type alias in a different .cpp file.

The following round about method should work for your needs.

```
class C
{
   public:

      // Use a base class for just the pointers.
      struct TBase
      {
         virtual ~TBase() {}
      };

      TBase* f();
      void g(TBase*);

      // Allow client code to define a concrete type using a template parameter.
      template <typename Data> struct T : TBase
      {
         Data data;
      };
};
```

Then, in a .cpp file, use:

```
using Type = C::T<std::string>;

Type* obj = new Type;
obj->data = "Some string";

C c;
c.g(obj);
TBase* ptr = c.f();
```